# I need to restrict the four input values from the backspace using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to restrict the  four input values from the backspace  using javascript . But i don't know how to store the four input values in single variable. my code is below,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
         var input = $('#test1');
         input.on('keydown', function () {
             var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

             if (key == 8)
                 return false;
         }); // $('#test1'), $('#test2'), $('#test3'), $('#test4') my four text input
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple selectors separated by `,`

`var $inputs = $('#test1, #test2, #test3, ...');`

Answer (score 1):

You can either repeat the code for all four inputs, or create a function that you can pass an input to and call it for each one, or apply a common class to the relevant inputs and pass a class selector instead of an ID.

Personally I'd go with this:

```
function disallowBackspace(input) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(input),
        evt = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if( (e.keyCode || e.which) == 8) {
                if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
    if( elem.addEventListener) elem.addEventListener('keydown',evt);
    else elem.attachEvent('onkeydown',evt);
}
disallowBackspace("test1");
disallowBackspace("test2");
disallowBackspace("test3");
disallowBackspace("test4");
```

No jQuery FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add a special class like `no-backspace` to all the input fields and then use it as a selector

```
$('.no-backspace').on('keydown', function () { .... }
```